# I need a method that automatically clicks a button in my program using only SWT in java

Tags: java, button, swt

I need a method that presses a specific button in my program when I tell it to, but I only am allowed to use SWT.

```
Button btnred = createButton(parent, "");`

public Button createButton(Composite parent, String text)
{
    Button btn = new Button(parent, SWT.PUSH);
    btn.setText(text);
    btn.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
    return btn;
}'

btnred.addMouseListener(new MouseListener()
{
    public void mouseDown(MouseEvent e)
    {
        btnred.setImage(redglow);
        rev.CheckChoice(one);
    }
    public void mouseUp(MouseEvent e)
    {
        btnred.setImage(red);
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseDoubleClick(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

});
```

Comment: What did you try so far? This is not a "do this for me"-site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can invoke the `Listener` of the `Button` programmatically by calling:

```
button.notifyListeners(SWT.Selection, new Event());
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me, also it must be notifyListeners not notifyListener otherwise i am given the error "The method notifyListener(int, Event) is undefined for the type Button"

Comment: @IuhasDan Then please post your setup in the question, i.e. how you set up the button, how you add the listener, etc.

Comment: can you look again please?

Comment: @IuhasDan Well, you're using a mouse listener rather than a selection listener. Just change my code to `SWT.MouseDown`.

Comment: @IuhasDan And potentially `SWT.MouseUp` afterwards.